# Possible to filter the posts or categories that XML-RPC users see in their mobile application?

Tags: filters, query, mobile, xml-rpc

Is it possible to filter the posts or categories that XML-RPC users see in their mobile application?

I have a plugin that hooks into `pre_get_posts` and `list_terms_exclusions` to do what I need it to do.  I've had requests to allow the same functionality on their mobile devices.

Comment: Funny. I was just watching this talk on wp.tv http://wordpress.tv/2010/01/23/daniel-jalkut-apis-boston10/ but it stopped after some minutes. Maybe the answer is hidden in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I discovered the answer to my question.

It is possible to filter the posts and categories that users see in their XML-RPC application.  The `pre_get_posts` and `list_terms_exclusions` filters are called via the blogger.getRecentPosts XML-RPC method.  Inside this function, it calls `wp_get_recent_posts` which uses `get_posts`.  In other words, there's really nothing special you have to do if you are hooking into the above filters.

My problem was that for my plugin, I was only filtering while in the admin: `if ( is_admin()`

**SOLUTION**

In order to make sure it only fires when requested through an XML-RPC application, all you have to do is check for the XMLRPC_REQUEST constant and hook into the `xmlrpc_call` action.

```
if ( defined ( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) && XMLRPC_REQUEST ) {
    add_action( 'xmlrpc_call', array( &$this, 'posts' ) );
}
```

Inside your callback, hook into the `pre_get_posts` and `list_terms_exclusions` filters.

Answer (score 2):

This [github repo](https://github.com/bangordailynews/WordPress-xmlrpc-extenders) has `bdn.getPosts` extended XML-RPC function to get category.

> Get 10 most recently modified posts in the sports category ($category can be either a slug or an ID)
>
> ```
>    `array( 1, $username, $password, 'post', 'sports', 10, array( 'orderby' => 'modified' ) );`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually experimented with it myself but when I cracked open the xmlrpc.php file I noticed several do actions for xmlrpc_call.

I suspect that you could add actions based on user type to the xmlrpc call.
E.g. blogger_getPost() can be hooked with xmlrpc_call when xmlrpc_call == blogger.getPost.